# FFmpeg claims OpenSSL is not compatible with GPL v3?

Tags: openssl, ffmpeg, licenses

[FFmpeg says in the 4.1 docs](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/md_LICENSE.html),

> The Fraunhofer FDK AAC and **OpenSSL libraries are under licenses which are incompatible with the GPLv2 and v3**. To the best of our knowledge, they are compatible with the LGPL.

But it seems the [OpenSSL license is Apache v2](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/LICENSE), and at least [according to Apache,](https://www.apache.org/licenses/GPL-compatibility.html),

> **The Free Software Foundation considers the Apache License, Version 2.0 to be a free software license, compatible with version 3 of the GPL.** The Software Freedom Law Center provides practical advice for developers about including permissively licensed source.

Why does FFmpeg claim that Apache 2 is incompatible with GPL v3?

Comment: I know ffmpeg was not in fedora for a long time because of licensing. OpenSSH came from BSD like ZFS so it may have iffy parts.

Comment: Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Github file you linked to clearly shows the license was modified, and that pretty recently:

> [@levitte](https://github.com/levitte) Change license to the Apache License v2.0 [1513331](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/151333164ece49fdba3fe5c4bbdc3333cd9ae66d) on
>   Dec 6, 2018

The license before that seems to be [some custom stuff](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/7c24f9d21cddd2bb30167153b05168fee7e3cf0b/LICENSE), known as the "OpenSSL license", which may not have been compatible with GPL (2 or 3).

And the docs you link to has the footnote:

> Generated on Tue Nov 6 2018 18:11:55 for FFmpeg by   doxygen 1.8.6

Comment: To further expand on this answer. OpenSSL git master is under Apache License v2.0. All other branches (including the current stable releases 1.1.1, 1.1.0 and 1.0.2) are under the old OpenSSL/SSLeay dual licence. The next stable version of OpenSSL (version 3.0) will be under the Apache License when it is released.

Comment: @MattCaswell that's not an extension, that's actually the right reason. If you make this an answer, I'll mark it as chosen. I didn't realize that OpenSSL 3.0 was not stable yet.